# Im trying to make my telegram bot send a profile picture for every username he recive but I keep gettig this Error

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I know that "UserProfilePhoto" is an object and cant be send on telegram but I dont know how to transform it in to photos and send it I keep getting this Error:

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'UserProfilePhotos'

```
import os
import telebot

API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXX"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_KEY)

#This function tries to get the user profile photo and I think here is the error

def send_photo(user):
    user_photos = bot.get_user_profile_photos(user)
    return user_photos

#This function finds the username in the message the bot recived 

def find_at(message):
    for text in message:
        if "@" in text:
            return text

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: "@" in msg.text)
def answer(message):
    text = message.text.split()
    at_text = find_at(text)
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    ANSWER = send_photo(user_id)
    bot.send_photo(message, ANSWER)
bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`userProfilePhotos`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.userprofilephotos.html) object represents a user’s profile pictures. It has a list called `photos` which contains user profile photos and every profile photo is a list of three [`PhotoSize`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.photosize.html) objects and they are comparable in terms of equality.
So you can do this:

```py
def get_photos(user):
    user_photos = bot.get_user_profile_photos(user)
    user_photos = user_photos.photos
    photos_ids = []
    for photo in user_photos:
        photos_ids.append(photo[0].file_id)
    return photos_ids

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: "@" in msg.text)
def answer(message):
    text = message.text.split()
    at_text = find_at(text)
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    photos_ids = get_photos(user_id)
    for photo_id in photos_ids:
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo_id)
```